# How to fix NetBeans6.9 UI inconsistency?

Tags: netbeans, config

I bought a new PC, so I installed NB6.9 on it, but I want to use UI configs from my old PC, so I copied "???.netbeans\6.9\config" from old PC to the new one.

The default key for F6 in NB is "Run Project", but in my old PC, I've set F6 to "Run File", while shift+F6 was assigned to "Run Project". Since I set them by hand on the old PC, they were consistent from the UI and the list in "Tools -> Options -> Keymap", but on the new PC, UI still display the default setting, while "Tools -> Options -> Keymap" shows my custom setting, and when I press F6, it uses my custom setting to "Run File", so my question is what do I need to do on the new PC to make the UI consistent with the list in "Tools -> Options -> Keymap", is there another config file somewhere I need to copy over ?

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans > Tools > options > keymap you can click the "Manage Profiles" button to export and import keymap profiles.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to reproduce your problem (see comments). I checked the Netbeans bug list but couldn't see anything outstanding that matched this scenario. I did however find [this discussion](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic21070.html&highlight=keymap) in the Netbeans forums regarding a similar issue in Netbeans 6.8. It appears to me that keymapping in Netbeans is prone to many (some recurring) issues.

I will try filing a bug report and we'll see what happens.

**UPDATE 2:**
I have filed a [bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189453) for this issue.

Comment: In my situation should I export or import keymap profiles, and to or from where ?

Comment: If I understand your objective correctly, you would do an export from Netbeans on the old PC and import on the new one.

Comment: I did what you said, exported keymap to a file on the old PC, and copied the zip file to the new PC, opened NB on the new PC, imported that zip file, restarted NB, but the the key mapping still looks correct in "Tools -> Options -> Keymap" and yet inconsistent on the GUI, why ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Perhaps Netbeans was confused by they direct copying of the config directory you did at the start. It's a pain but at this point I would uninstall Netbeans on the new machine, wipe any traces of the Netbeans directories in your profile, reinstall and try the import again. If that still doesn't work, you may want to check the Netbeans forums and/or file a bug report. Somebody else may still answer here with a solution too.

Comment: Strange thing, I uninstalled it, reinstalled it, imported the mapping, all projects, UI color setting showed up correctly and yet the F6 key still runs project, and even if I do it by hand, go through "Tools -> Options -> Keymap" to reassign it "Run file", the GUI toolbar still showed incorrectly.

Comment: I made the same changes through the key mapping settings on my installation of Netbeans 6.9 (set "Run Project to Shift-F6). After that, Shift-F6 runs the project but the hint on the toolbar and the "Run" menu show just F6. Is that what you see?

Comment: Yes, because I use Run File more, so I want to set F6 to "Run File", and Shift-F6 to "Run Project", after the manual change, the F6 key "does" run file, but the hint on the toolbar and the "Run" menu still show old setting, so I guess there must be another config file I need to touch to make the UI display correct info, which config file is it ?